# Дисперсия света в призме в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Нужно паписать прогу которая наглядно показывала бы дисперсию. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

1-й вариант. Взять [картинку](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/Prism_rainbow_schema.png), на которой изображена дисперсия света, например:

[image: призма]

и добавить в свою программу.

2-й вариант. Используя [законы дисперсии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8) рассчитать ход лучей спектра с каким-либо шагом и отобразить их на картинке. Рисовать стандартно на холсте (TImage и тп.).

Comment: Вставить картинку это не потянет. Прога должна показывать ход луча и его разложение на спктр.

Answer (score 0):

Вот прога в [рар архиве](http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=119913&d=1326379233). Использовал материал http://shpargalka.kz/fizika/dispersiya-sveta и  вики. Спасибо также программистам на этом сайте